# When trying to display an imported MUI icon I get the following errors: Invalid hook call and <ForwardRef(SvgIcon)> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When trying to display an imported MUI icon I get the following errors:

**Errors**

[image: 1. Invalid hook call 2. <ForwardRef(SvgIcon)> component]

**My Code**

```
import React from 'react'
import ThreeDRotation from '@mui/icons-material/ThreeDRotation';

export const Temp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <ThreeDRotation />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is this code for `SvgIcon.js` ?

Comment: @Kundan Hi, it's for ThreeDRotation icon

Comment: But the error is showing in `SvgIcon.js`, so kindly share that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you using the wrong import, you can try like this:

```js
import ThreeDRotation from '@mui/material/ThreeDRotation';
```

, you can try this: